# Frequency digit counting

Tags: c

I'm trying to find the frequency of digit into given string,which contain digit and letters. When i run the same program i get different result, look like random output. where is the problem ?

```
int main() {              

    char num[1001];
    int digit[10];
    int j,i;
    int count;
    scanf("%s",num);

    for(i=48;i<=57;i++)
    { 
      count = 0;
      for(j=0; num[j] != EOF;j++)
      {
        if(num[j] == i)
        {
          count++;
        }
      }
      printf("%d ",count);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Could you provide us with a set of input and output?

Comment: Try printing the value of the character where you expect `EOF` to be and the value of `EOF`.

Comment: What happens if you change the loop condition to `num[j] != '\0';`

Comment: Also, consider changing the loop to 'for (char ch = '0' ; ch <= '9' ; ch++)'. Easier to read vs 49. 57 constants.

Comment: Instead of going back and counting again, one could use `digit[10]` to place the digit, requiring only one pass.

Answer (score 0):

<s>You have missed an `&` in the line with `scanf` before `num`. Correct code should be:</s>

```c
scanf("%s", &num);
```

When you are scanning for the value, you need to provide the **address** of the variable. That is you let your program know where to put the value. **`&num`** points to the address of the variable `num`. But if you just write `scanf("%s",num)` you are providing value of the `num` variable, which you don't care at all. You'll be overwriting that value anyway.

---

At the end of the string, computer puts a null character `\0` whose ASCII value is 0, to denote that this is the end of the string. Kind of like a '.' but for a computer. So you check until you find the null character in the for loop like: `num[j] != '\0'` [Not EOF]

Comment: No, that's not true. The `%s` format in `scanf` is the one format that doesn't want the `&`: You pass in the array and `scanf` fills it. Note that `num` decays into a pointer to its first element when you pass it to a function.

Comment: Oh right! My bad!! I remember forgetting `&` in my codes and getting gibberish outputs. i thought OP had similar issues. And I jumped my gun there... Thanks for pointing out. Fixing it right now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to compare a char element with an integer type.
for example:

```
    char num[7] = {"ABC123");
        if (num[3] == 1)
    {
       printf("True\n");
    }
    else
    {
      printf("False\n");
    }
    return 0;

    // This will return False, even though the element at index 3 is "1".
```

I've ran your code, and it seems like the output is the same given the same input.

Edit:

We wanted to compare a two digit number to a char data type - which is essentially a character - a **one** digit number/case.

When we take a number `N` and modulo by 10, we get the last digit, example:

`48 % 10 = 8`

To get the first digit we simply divide by 10, and take the quotient, example:

`48 / 10 = 4 (remainder 8).`

With this knowledge, we can compare the `n-th` char with first digit, and the `n+1-th` char with the last one (given that we only compare two digits, we'll stop at `n+1-th`).

**Tip**: a number char can be turned into a int using `char = char - '0'`

```
char num[1001];
int digit[10];
int j,i;
int count;
scanf("%s",num);

for(i=48;i<=57;i++)
{ 
  count = 0;
  for(j=0; num[j] != EOF;j++)
  {
    if(num[j] - '0' == i / 10 && num[j+1] - '0' == i % 10)
    {
        printf("%c", num[j] - '0');
        count++;
    }
  }
  printf("%d: %d \n",i, count);
}
printf("\n"); 
return 0;
// This code will print the digits and the frequency in a new line:
48: n times
49: n times
.
.
.
57: n times
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue here, it seems output is not readable properly
so try printing correctly like

`printf("%c=>%d ",i, count);`

so that you can read what number how many times. if you find wrong frequency,
post the input for which you are getting wrong output.